# In ASP.Net Core MVC, what's "value" used for in ControllerBase.StatusCode()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It's the second param. I don't see any documentation describing what happens when I return a StatusCode ObjectResult that has that param set.

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Creates a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult object by specifying a statusCode
    //     and value
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   statusCode:
    //     The status code to set on the response.
    //
    //   value:
    //     The value to set on the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The created Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult object for the response.
    [NonAction]
    public virtual ObjectResult StatusCode(int statusCode, object value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` will be the payload/body included in the response, formatted by the applicable media formatter.

For the code below and when using the `application/json` content-type, this will be

```
{ "a" : "foo", "b" : 1 }
```

---

```
public class Dto
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}


public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult MyAction()
    {
        var dto = new Dto { A = "foo", B = 1};
        return StatusCode(200, dto);
    }
}
```